# OpenSceneGraph Live Rendering

Tags: openscenegraph

When using osgviewer, you specify a .osg file to view and it displays it on the screen. Is it possible to then edit this scene graph live? As in, is it possible to add a node to the scene graph and then have the viewer automatically show this addition?

Comment: Don't ask questions with the [tag:c++] tag, without showing c++ code please.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use OpenSceneGraph so that to edit scene graphs live, but you have to do it programmatically. You would have to **design your own structure** of a scene graph using principles of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Then you can save your scene graphs using your own serializer, later read them from file and edit as you wish. For this, I recommend checking [OSG numerous tutorials](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/Tutorials) and [books](http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/documentation/books).

If your question is simply about whether you can edit sample `.osg` files live, then it might not be as straightforward since you need to know the structure of each scene in advance. Assuming that, as a user, you know the structure, then you can definitely introduce some changes (or tie the changes to certain keyboard events), and observe them live.

Answer (score 0):

Use OSGEdit to edit it live. It loads OSG file and it provides options to edit scenegraphs and their properties

http://osgedit.sourceforge.net/